# Show Node fields on Drupal Form

Tags: forms

I'm working on a form where I have added Company field as entity reference and which is type of auto complete. Is there any way, which can show other attribute of company content type like phone number and email in the form post selecting the company name.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your question pertains to Drupal 7 then you may want to take a look at the [Entity Reference Autofill](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_autofill)

> The Entity reference autofill module gives Entity reference fields an option to populate other form fields with data from selected referenced entities.